Animating a GameObject with Nav Mesh Agent with idle animation - Unity 3d
I have a Unity Assets store imported GameObject named Zombie1 with a Nav Mesh Agent component set and a Animator component (screenshot: ), and a animation named Z_Idle. I would like to implement the idle animation to my Zombie1 GameObject, so I stepped up the state parado, the boolean parameter also named parado and a transition to the the Z_Walk state named Parado-Walk with a condition parado set to true (screenshot of the animator window:  ). I also have this script linked in the Zombie1 gameobject:
using UnityEngine;

public class Inimigo : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;
    private UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Start()
    {
        agent.destination = player.position;
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        agent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (agent.velocity.magnitude == 0)
        {
            animator.SetBool("parado", false);          
        }
        else if (agent.remainingDistance > agent.stoppingDistance)
        {
            animator.SetBool("parado", true);            
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("parado", false);
        }
    }
}

When I press the play button, the zombie is not doing the animations. What should I do?

Does you navmesh agent have a destination? The navmesh agent won't move without one.

@MarkManson, thanks for the comment. I added your suggestion to my code and now it is moving, but the animation is still not working.

Thinking about it now, sorry I didn't fully realize the question I was actually thinking it was an animation you wanted to play when the player is moving. The animator needs to have exit transitions for the idle and walk, so Enter -> Idle -> Exit and Enter -> WalkAnimation -> Exit, It's a lot easier to set it up in that regard then having the bools with their corresponding values (like to idle IsIdle is true for instance). If you want I can add in an answer with proper screenshots for more detail if what I've said isn't clear.

@MarkManson if you don't mind, please add an answer. I'm totally noob in this section

try adding a debug statement to see if this block of code is reached
else if (agent.remainingDistance > agent.stoppingDistance)
            {
                animator.SetBool("parado", true);            
            }

once you find out if that portion of code is reached you might wanna check if it is set to false right after being set to true.
To find out, you need to add inside your update function the statement
Debug.Log(animator.GetBool("parado")); to constantly check if your boolean switches values instantly because if that is the case it wont stay in the moving state long enough for you to visualize the animation.
hope this helps!

Thanks for the answer. I added to my code the line of code you suggested in the Update method and the output is false only in the first and second line on console. For the other lines the output is true. What should I do?

Note: I edited my question here in stack overflow. For the updated code, please see the edited question.

So this is how I would typically setup a basic animation controller:

Where in I have the idle animation be the default animation that plays, what that means is that when the game object is instantiated or spawned in, it will play that animation.
I also have on one parameter on the side "IsWalking"

The Enter Transition (sorta hard to see in the image, but I've selected the arrow going into Walking Animation) is setup to have a Condition of IsWalking is true, pretty simple stuff. The way it works if at any point we set this bool to true, from whatever animation, it will transition into it.

The Exit Transition, is pretty much the same setup, but in this case we have the bool IsWalking set to false, so in that regard, if we ever set the bool to false it'd exit out.
So just to add an extra note here, specific to my comment, animations need to have a way to exit out of an animation, otherwise they are just going to play the same animation on loop, so with this setup, things should transition in and out of animations correctly.
To conclude I'll add code that should work with this setup, I'll use your code from the question and modify to work in with this.
using UnityEngine;

public class Inimigo : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;
    private UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Start()
    {
        agent.destination = player.position;
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        agent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Let's set the animator IsWalking to false if the navmesh agent has stopped
        if (agent.isStopped)
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsWalking", false);          
        }//Otherwise let's set the animator IsWalking bool to true
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsWalking", true);
        }
    }
}

Let me know if there are any issues with this, I have not tested this but I work with the animation controller all day lol so I feel like it should be working right off the bat.

I tested your suggestions and it continues not working as it is supposed to work. I guess here in the comment section in stack overflow isn't the best place to show you my code and my animator controller, what can we do so?
